# C# Windows Forrm "MouseWheel" does not appear in zoomControl1

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I want to use the code below, but the "MouseWheel" event is not working.

```
private void zoomControl1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      
       if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && e.Delta > 0)
       {
          zoomControl1.Zoom += 0.1f;
       }
       else if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control && e.Delta < 0)
       {
          zoomControl1.Zoom -= 0.1f;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Did you register the event (manually or in the designer) ? If not you need something like: `...MouseWheel += zoomControl1_MouseWheel ...`

Comment: What is `ZoomControl`?

Comment: Legacy Windows versions used to raise MouseWheel on the control that has the focus.  That changed in Win10, it has a new option named "Scroll inactive windows when I hover over them" and is turned on by default.  Which is *probably* what you wanted, you may have to pinvoke SendMessage() to pass the WM_MOUSEWHEEL message to that 'zoom control' on old versions.